# NavDrawer usando activities ao invés de fragments

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragment, android-activity

Estou tentando implantar uma **NavDrawer** no meu app mas o [exemplo](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/) que eu vi usa **Fragments** ao invés de **Activity** que eu ja estava usando, eu encontrei um bloco que trata os Fragments.

Parte do código que usa Fragments:

```
private void displayView(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        fragment = new HomeFragment();
        break;
    case 1:
        fragment = new FindPeopleFragment();
        break;
    case 2:
        fragment = new PhotosFragment();
        break;
    case 3:
        fragment = new CommunityFragment();
        break;
    case 4:
        fragment = new PagesFragment();
        break;
    case 5:
        fragment = new WhatsHotFragment();
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    } else {
        // error in creating fragment
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}
```

Gostaria de saber se tem como fazer com que o NavDrawer trabalhe com Activity ou então se tem como converter as activities que eu tenho pra Fragment (deve ser trabalhoso) pra que eu possa implantar a NavDrawer no meu app.

Obrigado desde já.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Infelizmente não é possível implementar um NavigationDrawer utilizando activities do jeito que você quer.
Na realidade, o que você pode fazer, é disparar intents para iniciar suas Activities quando um item do NavigationDrawer for clicado. Mas acho que o comportamento não vai ser o que você quer.

Tendo dito isso, sugiro então que você transforme suas activities em fragmentos. Na realidade, antes de criar uma activity, sempre se pergunte se você realmente precisa dela e/ou você não pode trocá-la por um fragmento. Fragmentos são muito poderosos e ajudam você a modularizar e reutilizar componentes da aplicação.

Comment: você teria algum link pra um tutorial de como transformar minhas activities pra fragments? Terei de refazer todo o meu trabalho?

Comment: @AllanChrystian, o lifecycle de uma activity e de um fragment são parecidos... Então, apesar de que você vai ter que fazer o port do código, o trabalho vai ser mais na hora de utilizar os fragmentos na aplicação do que na hora de portar o codigo pra um fragment. Eu sugiro que você mesmo faça o port pra você se familiarizar com fragments. Mas aqui vão dois links: https://prezi.com/fh2uslbr1xs3/the-fragment-transition/ e https://github.com/OmniDebt/OmniDebt-Android/wiki/Convert-Activity-to-Fragment

Comment: Complementando e não querendo ser chato, ao criar um novo projeto com navdrawer, o código vem todo comentado, você pode dar uma lida nele e facilmente consiguirá adicionar fragmentos. sendo que no código ja vem 1 fragmento como subclasse como exemplo, basta copialo e renomealo, e se der uma olhada melhor no código vc consegue ver aonde o fragment é chamado e criado. Eu aprendi assim a utilizar o navdrawer.

Comment: Obrigado, irei dar uma olhada